outlook.office.com Login-Token reuse
I have strong PowerShell coding skills and am developing an app to automate and modify settings in the OWA (Outlook Web Access) frontend. For this, I’m using Selenium to interact with the website https://outlook.office.com/mail/. My app uses MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication), which works seamlessly without any issues during the initial login. Since accessing the settings requires mandatory MFA authentication, the user must authenticate securely.
However, while the tool runs in the background, I’d prefer not to force the user to log in with MFA every single day. I want the tool to operate as long as the authentication token remains valid. Once the token expires or becomes invalid, only then should the user be prompted to log in again via MFA.
Here’s where I’m struggling. I don’t know how to save and reuse the token during its validity period. From my research, I believe I need to use the OpenIdConnect token, but I’m unsure how to retrieve, save, and reuse it effectively in PowerShell with Selenium for a validated login.
I found the website https://labs.lares.com/owa-cap-bypass/, but it is not directly related to PowerShell.
Is there someone who can point me in the right direction or provide guidance on how to achieve this?
Thanks,
Manfred
